# Docker container SQL Server with Access database engine

Tags: sql-server, docker, ms-access

I'm new to docker and I love the implementation of it since
I wont suffer with auto running with SQL Server now which eat up my
precious MEMORY.

Though when trying to run a code to allow "import" data's from a "Access.mdb" file
using MS Access Database Engine but I got stuck with it..

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
RECONFIGURE;
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',N'AllowInProcess', 1
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',N'DynamicParameters', 1
```

I already installed the MSAccessDatabaseEngine in my PC (not in docker) and when I ran it
the error is:

> A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

So  I think it should be installed inside the container, my question is... is there anyway around to install this one together with the SQL Server container?

Cheers!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Docker containers are, well, somewhat contained. Why do you think that software installed on the host computer would be available to processes running inside Docker containers? Which SQL Server image are you using in Docker?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - Hi! im using sql server from docker hub. How I understand your question is that this 'MS Access Database Engine' acts as the ODBC connection which I thinking SQL Server is not able to find it inside the container. Thats why I think it should be installed inside the container. If there's no way around then I have to go back to old ways to install the SQL server instead to the host pc. :)